# AutoFocus - Blazor - TinyMCE

Tags: blazor, tinymce

I am using the Blazor version of TinyMCE and I wish to set Autofocus.

When I understand the documentation then I should set "The value of an editor instance id".

```
<Editor Id="txtEditor"
    @bind-Value="content"
    JsConfSrc="sample"
    ApiKey="empty" />
```

and my Javascript as follow:

```
window.sample = {
height: '100%',
menubar: false,
selector: 'textarea',
**auto_focus: 'txtEditor',**
plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table paste imagetools wordcount'
],
toolbar: [{ name: 'history', items: ['undo', 'redo'] },
{ name: 'styles', items: ['styleselect'] },
{ name: 'other', items: ['table', 'editimage', 'link', 'image', 'insertdatetime'] },
{ name: 'formatting', items: ['bold', 'italic'] },
{ name: 'lists', items: ['numlist', 'bullist'] },
{ name: 'alignment', items: ['alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'alignjustify'] },
{ name: 'indentation', items: ['outdent', 'indent'] },
{ name: 'last', items: ['fullscreen'] }
],
branding: false,
elementpath: false
}
```

Unfortunately it does not auto focus. Could you kindly assist?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: Is running for me without issues. When auto_focus is set, after load page, without clicking on component, if I press keys, the editor shows what I'm writing.

Comment: Hi Dani. Thank you. Unfortunatly not for me. I will have to see what is happening here then

Comment: I just copy-paste your sample.

Comment: Thank you ver much. Then it is clear to me that the wrapping components are bringing me a head ache. I appreciate it alot!